# if statement is not working the way i want it to using jsoup

Tags: android

**Am trying to use an if statement how ever its not doing what i want it to.**

Am trying to get all the images extracted from html source using jsoup some items in html dont have images so there is no ( img ) tag's in them so here is the if statement i use

```
 Elements imagess = doc.select("img[src$=.jpg]");

              //Elements imagess = doc.select("img");
                for (Element table : doc.select("div[class=listing-content]")) {
// Identify all the table row's(tr)
                    for (Element row : table.select("div:gt(0)")) {
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        String[] imgg = new String[imagess.size()];

                        ArrayList products = new ArrayList();

                        for (int i = 0; i < imagess.size(); i++)

                            if (imagess.toString().contains("https://ssli")) {

                                imgg[i] = imagess.get(i).attr("src");
                            } else {
                                imgg[i] = "https://afs.googleusercontent.com/gumtree-com/noimage_thumbnail_120x92_v2.png";
                            }
```

so while looping if (https://ssli) is found during the loop process then extract the current found
`imgg[i] = imagess.get(i).attr("src");`
else let it add blank image url
 `imgg[i] = "https://afs.googleusercontent.com/gumtree-com/noimage_thumbnail_120x92_v2.png";`

here is the part of html code extracted from page is has more image and no image tags

```
<div class="listing-content">
<h2 class="listing-title" itemprop="name">
Faulty Xbox 36
</h2>
<p class="listing-description
hide-fully-to-m"
itemprop="description">
Turns on but tray broken so can't load games .
Sold as seen
</p>
<ul class="listing-attributes inline-list hide-fully-to-m">
</ul>
<div class="listing-location" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Place">
<span class="truncate-line" itemprop="name">
Sunbury-on-Thames, Surrey
</span>
</div>
<strong class="listing-price txt-emphasis"
itemprop="price">£20</strong>
<strong class="listing-posted-date txt-normal truncate-line" itemprop="adAge">
<span class="hide-visually">Ad posted </span>
11 mins ago
</strong>
</div>
</a>
<span class="save-ad listing-save-ad"
data-savead="channel:savead-1131358978">
<span class="hide-visually">Save this ad</span>
<span class="icn-star iconu-m txt-quaternary" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</span>
</article>
</li>
<li>
<article class="listing-maxi" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" data-q=ad-1131358703>
<a class="listing-link" href="/p/video-games/xbox-360-cod-/1131358703" itemprop="url">
<div class="listing-side">
<div class="listing-thumbnail ">
<img src="" data-lazy="https://ssli.ebayimg.com/00/s/ODAwWDYwMA==/z/uFgAAOSwMmBV4eSL/$_26.JPG"
alt="" itemprop="image"
class="hide-fully-no-js"/>
<noscript>
<img src="https://ssli.ebayimg.com/00/s/ODAwWDYwMA==/z/uFgAAOSwMmBV4eSL/$_26.JPG" alt="" itemprop="image"/>
</noscript>
</div>
<div class="listing-meta">
<ul class="inline-list txt-center">
<li>1<span class="hide-visually"> images</span>
<span class="icn-camera txt-quaternary" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<div class="listing-content">
<h2 class="listing-title" itemprop="name">
Xbox 360 cod
</h2>
<p class="listing-description truncate-paragraph
hide-fully-to-m"
itemprop="description">
Call of duty advanced warfare £12
Call of duty modern warfare 3 £5
Black ops 2 SOLD
Both for £15
No offers
</p>
<ul class="listing-attributes inline-list hide-fully-to-m">
</ul>
<div class="listing-location" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Place">
<span class="truncate-line" itemprop="name">
Norwich, Norfolk
</span>
</div>
<strong class="listing-price txt-emphasis"
itemprop="price">£1</strong>
<strong class="listing-posted-date txt-normal truncate-line" itemprop="adAge">
<span class="hide-visually">Ad posted </span>
13 mins ago
</strong>
</div>
</a>
<span class="save-ad listing-save-ad"
data-savead="channel:savead-1131358703">
<span class="hide-visually">Save this ad</span>
<span class="icn-star iconu-m txt-quaternary" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</span>
</article>
</li>
<li>
<article class="listing-maxi" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" data-q=ad-1131358320>
<a class="listing-link" href="/p/xbox-one/xbox-one-w-kinect-5-games-forza-horizon-2-incl.-blu-ray-2-controllers-2-charger-cables-1-mic/1131358320" itemprop="url">
<div class="listing-side">
<div class="listing-thumbnail ">
<img src="" data-lazy="https://ssli.ebayimg.com/00/s/OTYwWDk2MA==/z/n4AAAOSwLVZV4eQ1/$_26.JPG"
alt="" itemprop="image"
class="hide-fully-no-js"/>
<noscript>
<img src="https://ssli.ebayimg.com/00/s/OTYwWDk2MA==/z/n4AAAOSwLVZV4eQ1/$_26.JPG" alt="" itemprop="image"/>
</noscript>
</div>
<div class="listing-meta">
<ul class="inline-list txt-center">
<li>8<span class="hide-visually"> images</span>
<span class="icn-camera txt-quaternary" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

as you can se html with images has tag listing-thumbnail ones without it dont have that.

also it seems like

```
if (imagess.get(i).toString().contains("https://ssli")){

                                imgg[i] = imagess.get(i).attr("src");
                            } else {
                                imgg[i] = "https://afs.googleusercontent.com/gumtree-com/noimage_thumbnail_120x92_v2.png";
                            }
```

the code in else dont fire not sure why , it prints out like this when found and not found

```
for (int j = 0; j < hrefElements.size(); j++) {
                        System.out.println("title: " + titlee[j]);
                        System.out.println("description: " + description[j]);
                        System.out.println("distance: " + distance[j]);
                       System.out.println("posted: " + posted[j]);
                        System.out.println("price: " + pricee[j]);
                        System.out.println("meta: " + listingmeta[j]);
                        System.out.println("link: " + linkss[j]);

System.out.println("img-link: " + imgg[j]);

                    }
                        return products;
                    }
                }

          } catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
            return null;
        }
```

this returns when found like this
`System.out.println("img-link: " + "https://ssli.ebayimg.com/00/s/OTYwWDk2MA==/z/n4AAAOSwLVZV4eQ1/$_26.JPG");`
else when not found
`System.out.println("img-link: " + "");`    blank rather then being blank i want it to add my custom link in else

Answer (score 1):

`imagess` appears to be a collection of some kind. Instead of stringifying the collection:

```
if (imagess.toString().contains("https://ssli"))
```

you probably wanted to examine an element of the collection:

```
if (imagess.get(i).toString().contains("https://ssli"))
```

Comment: can you check the editing post sir , i think the else is not fireing because it leaves the System.out.println : blank rather then adding my custom link in else